# Finding consecutive elements in a vector

Tags: c++

I am working on a problem where I have to create subvectors from a bigger vector. If the elements in the vector are consecutive I have to create a vector of those elements. If there are elements which are not consecutive then a vector of that single elements is created. My logic is as below

```
vector<int> vect;
for (int nCount=0; nCount < 3; nCount++)
    vect.push_back(nCount);

vect.push_back(5);
vect.push_back(8);
vector<int>::iterator itEnd;

itEnd = std::adjacent_find (vect.begin(), vect.end(), NotConsecutive());
```

The functor `NotConsecutive`is as below

```
return (int first != int second-1);
```

So I am expecting the `std::adjacent_find` will give me back the iterators such that I can create vector one{0,1,2,3}, vector two{5} and vector{8}. But I am not sure if there is any simpler way?

Edit:I forgot to mention that I have  `std::adjacent_find` in a loop as

```
while(itBegin != vect.end())
{
    itEnd = std::adjacent_find (vect.begin(), vect.end(), NotConsecutive());
    vector<int> groupe;
    if( std::distance(itBegin, itEnd) < 1)
    {

        groupe.assign(itBegin, itBegin+1);
    }
    else
    {
        groupe.assign(itBegin, itEnd);
    }

    if(boost::next(itEnd) != vect.end())
    {
       itBegin = ++itEnd;                           
    }
    else
    {
       vector<int> last_element.push_back(itEnd);
    }
}
```

Does it make any sense?

Comment: +1 for using adjacent find and not hand crafted logic.

Comment: If you read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) you will see that the function returns an iterator to the *first* of the adjacent elements. You have to use it to check for the end of the consecutive series yourself.

Comment: Does return (int first != int second-1); really compile?!

Comment: You will have to do some iteration in any case. I don't think there is a way significantly simpler than this.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, it's probably easier and clearer to implement what you want by manually iterating through the collection, as no standard algorithm function really matches what you want. Also, by reading the linked reference, it doesn't seem that `std::adjacent_find` will be able to find the single entries.

Comment: I have to wonder why you'd do things this way. If you've just verified that elements are identical, why store all of them at all? Why not just store one element, and a count of how often it occurred in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't find any clear disadvantage of using a simple hand-crafted loop instead of standard functions:

```
void split(const std::vector<int> &origin, vector<vector<int> > &result)
{
  result.clear();
  if(origin.empty()) return;

  result.resize(1);
  result[0].push_back(origin[0]);

  for(size_t i = 1; i < origin.size(); ++i)
  {
    if(origin[i] != origin[i-1] + 1) result.push_back(vector<int>());
    result.back().push_back(origin[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: easy to understand.  I'd probably use iterators instead though.

Comment: Would also give the function a more informative name than 'split'.

Comment: Or with iterators, true (I particularly like the idiom vector[i-1] more than *(it-1)). The name is up to OP :)

Comment: It may not be difficult but it took me a while to understand.. Too much awesomeness ...

Comment: Voted down because I find a bad advice to not use standard algorithms when they fullfill the job. It makes the code far more readable and a common vocabulary among us c++ programmers.

Comment: @GermánDiago Standard algorithms are a good tool most of the times, but being forced to use them when they do not make things easier is a bad thing. `std::adjacent_find` does not solve the whole problem, so you need to iterate anyway. @hmjd's answer is great, but it requires either a lambda function (c++11) or to create an external functor if we translate it into c++03. Again, I see no advantage against a simple loop. Standard algorithms are tools, and a programmer must be able to judge when a tool is better than other.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger In this case I would write an algorithm called adjacent_find_greedy based on adjacent_find. I leave impl as an exercise, it´s not hard. Instead of two elements, it would find the longest consecutive sequence and would return a range (two iterators, I mean in this case) containing the consecutive sequence. With that range, you can: build a vector of consecutive elements and continue from the last with the next adjacent_find_greedy. Chances are users will understand this algorithm better than a raw for loop when reading.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger: I could write adjacent_find_greedy also without the help of adjacent_find. But the important matter for me here is to choose an understandable name. That's what I meant all the time.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what is being requested. It does not use `adjacent_find()` but manually iterates through the `vector` populating a `vector<vector<int>>` containing the extracted sub-vectors. It is pretty simple, IMO.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vect { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };

    // List of subvectors extracted from 'vect'.
    // Initially populated with a single vector containing
    // the first element from 'vect'.
    //
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> sub_vectors(1, std::vector<int>(1, vect[0]));

    // Iterate over the elements of 'vect',
    // skipping the first as it has already been processed.
    //
    std::for_each(vect.begin() + 1,
                  vect.end(),
                  [&](int i)
                  {
                      // It the current int is one more than previous
                      // append to current sub vector.
                      if (sub_vectors.back().back() == i - 1)
                      {
                          sub_vectors.back().push_back(i);
                      }
                      // Otherwise, create a new subvector contain
                      // a single element.
                      else
                      {
                          sub_vectors.push_back(std::vector<int>(1, i));
                      }
                  });

    for (auto const& v: sub_vectors)
    {
        for (auto i: v) std::cout << i << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0, 1, 2, 3,
5,
8,
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/ZM9ssk.

Comment: +1 Though `sub_vectors[sub_vectors_idx].back()` would probably a bit more streamlined than `*(sub_vectors[sub_vectors_idx].end() - 1)`.

Comment: And maybe using a `sub_vectors_iter` instead of a `sub_vectors_idx` would also be a bit more idiomatic. This would alleviate the need for separating the `push_back` from the increment and thus the need for a two-lines `else` case (and in turn the need for ugly `{}`s, but that may be subjective). Thus making it even more streamlined (and there's nothing better and more pleasing than a `std::algorithm` streamlined to utter perfection ;)).

Comment: @ChristianRau, could actually just get rid of the idx and use `back().back()` to access the current subvector.

Comment: Very elegant. Easy to understand..Took me a day to come up with the wrong solution in the original question...

Answer (score 2):

Due to the limitations of [`std::adjacent_find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) you can't use it quite the way you want to. However it can still be useful.

What you *can* do is to iterate over the collection, and use `std::adjacent_find` in a loop, with the last returned iterator (or your outer loop iterator for the first call) until it returns `end`. Then you will have a complete set of consecutive elements. Then continue the outer loop from where the last call to `std::adjacent_find` returned a non-end iterator.